# How to insert Roles into pre-generated ASP.NET database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, roles

I am working on a project that is using ASP.NET MVC and Visual Studio 2015. We are using the pre-generated database that comes with Visual Studio (I have added other tables, but that shouldn't matter with this.) I am creating a registration page for a role I want defined as an "Expert". I need the AspNetRole table to have this role inside of it. If I just go in and type it in directly to the databse, my other project members won't have this information. I have looked for this, but all I get is how to create a page for an admin that literally creates new roles. I do not want that. I understand how to set a user as role, but I need that role created in my database first. Is it something that goes in my startup.cs file? I'm sure how or where to do this. Any other information would also be helpful, for I am new to working with roles.Thank you.

Comment: when you initialize the app you can check if the role exists, if not insert the role

Comment: And exactly how/where would I do that? That's what I was assuming, but I'm really not sure how to do that.

Comment: @natemiklas1 if any answer helps you, don't forget to sign as correct answer! ;) hope it helped you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this in your `startup.cs`.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    ConfigureAuth(app);
    CreateRoles();
}


private void CreateRoles()
{
    ApplicationDbContext _context = new ApplicationDbContext();

    var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(_context));

    // creating Creating Expertrole   
    if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Expert"))
    {
        var role = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole();
        role.Name = "Expert";
        roleManager.Create(role);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What i did in a similar case, was check if in the table exists the role if not, added:

```
var context = new DatabaseContext();
if(!context.AspNetRoles.any(x=>x.role.equals("roleName"))){context.AspNetRoles.Add(new AspNetRoles{Role="roleName"}); context.SaveChanges();}
//Follow the normal process, in that case now is created
```

Comment: Where are you putting this?

Comment: At the moment when you initialize the app, in the app_start